# Turned off margin on sections, still getting space in between sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to experiment with parallax scrolling, so I came up with the following HTML, using the Bootstrap framework:

```
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>work</li>
          <li>services</li>
          <li>about</li>
          <li>news</li>
          <li>contact</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="social_media_icons"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <section class="background-fixed">
        <h1 class="title_desc">Company Name</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="description_slide">
        <h2>Partnering with forward-thinking companies to build brands and design the products, services and digital experiences that bring them to life.</h2>
      </section>
      <section class="featured_work">
        <h1>Featured Work</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, dolorem splendide pri ne, habeo petentium hendrerit sit cu. Usu cibo dolores ei, duo id omnium definiebas, quo te esse illum dissentias. Soleat concludaturque sea at. Illum nobis putent per ex, nec tibique molestiae te, te sea sint quidam. In eum principes consulatu, hinc nemore nominavi his ei.

Nec elitr invidunt et, te exerci elaboraret usu, in dicit noluisse pri. Qui cu facete nostrum, et dico veniam pri. An sit eros velit, commune conclusionemque ius an. Choro molestie sit no, democritum disputando ne has.

Mazim efficiendi voluptatibus sea ne, vitae intellegam adversarium nam ex. Ex habeo libris everti mel, eum et putent nemore utroque. Alii doming aliquip quo et, sed novum discere mediocritatem ei. Te cum agam causae consetetur, qui accusam albucius placerat an, nec at eius phaedrum.

Populo nemore persecuti per et, amet theophrastus ius cu. Eruditi vocibus cu sed, alia erroribus assueverit usu in, his ne meliore rationibus. Malorum laoreet sed in, impetus aperiam et pro. Pro et ludus iriure efficiantur.

Purto lorem scriptorem ei vel, usu invidunt accusata dignissim id. Feugiat constituam et vix, putant platonem per ad. Erat posse ridens sit te, iisque labores eu ius. Ex pri quodsi impetus phaedrum, in dicant officiis vix, ei ponderum deserunt duo.
          </p>
      </section>
      <section class="happy_clients">
        <h1>Happy Clients</h1>
      </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Made Together
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        FIND US

199 Cleveland Street
Surry Hills, NSW 2010
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        LET'S TALK

Send us an Email
(02) 8006 5089
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        PROJECT ENQUIRIES

        Let’s get started -
        Project planner
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
```

Then here's my css

```
/* Body */
body{
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}

/* Header section */
header{
  top: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

nav{
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

nav ul li:last{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

/* Background slide */
h1.title_desc{
  top: 160px;
  font-size: 70px;
}

section{
  height: 510px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.background-fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  z-index: -2;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Slide over bottom slide */
.description_slide{
  background: transparent url('../imgs/trans.png') repeat;
  color: white;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.description_slide > h2{
  top: 200px;
  position:  relative;
}

/* Rest of the slides */
/* Featured work */


/* Footer */
footer{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

If you look at the JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ph9x38o5/1/), you can see spacing between the sections. I tried setting the margins on my section tabs to 0px, still, nothing works.

Any ideas why?

(EDIT: There's also a mysterious margin on the right side of the sections in the JSFiddle that's only there when you include Bootstrap. I'd like to ask about that happening as well - I don't get that happening on my desktop machine, is this anything to be worried about?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin you are seeing is caused  by your `h1` elements.

Try to add the following to your CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

You can see it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4nmsh30/).

Edit:
In response to your question in the comments:
That's caused by a padding on your `body`. Try changing your `body` CSS into the following:

```
body {
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4nmsh30/4/).

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixes things. However, I also notice that there's a gap in between the sections and the right edge of the page, as soon as I add Bootstrap as an external file. (https://jsfiddle.net/g4nmsh30/1/) Any clue as to why that's happening?